# Why do i get a syntax error on line 13? (pico-8)

Tags: lua

I want to teach myself to program, I thought pico-8 fits me pretty well but I'm just really confused since on line 13 there is only function `_update` ... How did I mess this up?

The syntax error is, unclosed function at line 13 (tab 0)

```
local guy_x
local guy_y

    -- lua scripting language

function _init()
    -- all the code that happens
    -- when the cart is firt run
    guy_x=64
    guy_y=64
end

function _update()
    --  all the code that
    -- updates the game state
    if btn(1) then
  guy_x+=1
  
end

function _draw()
    -- all the code that
    -- drwas thing to the screen
    cls() -- clears screen!
    rect(10,20,100,60,12) -- draws a blue rectangle
    -- rect(x1,y1,x2,y2,color)
    circ(20,20,20,14) -- draws a pink circle
    pset(90,50,9) -- draws one pixel
    rectfill(85,50,90,40,9)
    circfill(guy_x,guy_y,5,9)
    --  circfill(x,y,radius,color
end
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, nvm I'm actually stupid I just forgot to write `end` after `if btn(1)then guy_x+=1`

fixed:

```
function _update()
    --  all the code that
    -- updates the game state
    if btn(1) then
  guy_x+=1
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, that's easily done... I am new to Lua and fell into same trap!

Comment: That's why proper indentation is so important, it helps in finding such errors :)